# Finding level curves of this function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$x^{2}+2ky+y^{2}=u(x,y,k)$$

If $k$ is made constant, what are the level curves of $u$?

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find the set of points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation
$$x^2+2ky + y^2 = u$$
for $k$ and $u$ constants. First, you can complete the square to get
$$x^2 + (y+k)^2 = u+k^2.$$
What does the set of points satisfying this equation look like?